# Тёмная тема PySide6

Tags: python, windows-10, pyside6, darkmode

Как можно установить тёмную тему программу? 
Я попробовал этот **[способ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74505698/22584786)**.

```py
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow)
import sys
sys.argv += ['-platform', 'windows:darkmode=2']


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Но ничего не меняется:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понял, в последних версиях этот способ не работает. 
Я перерыл кучу сайтов, ничего не нашёл.

По крайней мере мне нужно, чтобы эта панелька была чёрной, как на следующем скрине:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: а способ с установкой `app.setPalette( get_darkModePalette( app ) )` вы попробовали?

Comment: @S.Nick попробовал, цвет меняет всё, кроме самой панели с заголовком.

Comment: Панелька становится чёрной, если я поставлю тёмную тему windows и при этом оставлю get_darkModePalette, но мне-то нужно, чтоб панель была чёрной везде.

Comment: Вы говорите, чтобы панель была чёрной везде - это я понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду во всех `ОС` и версиях `PySide` и `PyQt`? Если так, то мне кажется что надо делать приложение без рамок и в нем делать заголовок какой вам надо.

Comment: @S.Nick ну, пусть даже только в Windows 10, что в таком случае делать?

Comment: Sorry, у меня нет ни Windows 10, ни  PySide6, чтобы попробовать. А приложения с окнами без границ делаются примерно так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A217323+FramelessWindowHint

Comment: это проверяли https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75962079/how-to-use-the-chromium-dark-mode-flag-enable-force-dark-in-pyside6

Comment: это способ для работы с Chromium, вряд ли он работает со мной